# SQL query to determine value based on monthly sum

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[DB fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VsyHuQkB)

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE cat (
    c_id int,
    c_date DATE,
    c_sit VARCHAR(3),
    c_value int,
    c_category VARCHAR(1)
);
```

with the following data:

| c_id | c_date | c_sit | c_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 147121 | 2022-06-06 | 25 | 4 |
| 147122 | 2022-06-06 | 23 | 3 |
| 147123 | 2022-06-07 | 25 | 5 |
| 147124 | 2022-11-23 | 25 | 1 |
| 147125 | 2022-11-16 | 25 | 3 |
| 147126 | 2023-10-08 | 25 | 2 |
| 147127 | 2023-10-09 | 25 | 5 |
| 147128 | 2022-04-14 | 25 | 4 |
| 147129 | 2022-04-15 | 25 | 6 |
| 147130 | 2022-04-16 | 25 | 1 |

Column `c_category` is currently null, and its values need to be determined. I need a SQL query for REDSHIFT such that:

- If `c_sit='25'` and sum of `c_value` for a month is > 7, all rows of that month will have 'a' in `c_category` column, else 'b'.

Desired result is:

```
(c_id, c_date, c_sit, c_value, c_category)
(147121,'2022-06-06','25',4,'a'),
(147122,'2022-06-06','23',3,''),
(147123,'2022-06-07','25',5,'a'),
(147124,'2022-11-23','25',1,'b'),
(147125,'2022-11-16','25',3,'b'),
(147126,'2023-10-08','25',2,'b'),
(147127,'2023-10-09','25',5,'b'),
(147128,'2022-04-14','25',4,'a'),
(147129,'2022-04-15','25',6,'a'),
(147130,'2022-04-16','25',1,'a');
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your rule. It seems from your desired result that if  a `c_value` is not '25', then that row should have a `c_category` of ''? Also should a non-25 row's `c_value` be considered or ignored when calculating the monthly sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE cat 
SET c_category = CASE 
                    WHEN c_sit = '25' AND 
                        SUM(c_value) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', c_date)) > 7 
                        THEN 'a'
                    ELSE 'b'
                 END;
```

I used **UPDATE** statement that will be used to modify rows(*which in this case is c_category*).

The **CASE** statement- what it does is to check if the certain condition is met and if so it returns a value.So in this cases it checks if **c_sit** is equal to 25 and the sum **c_value** in a month is greater than 7 and if it is true then **c_category** is equal to 'a' otherwise 'b'.

The **SUM** function- its purpose here is  to compute the sum of **c_value** over each month, using the **PARTITION BY**  to group the data by month.

Now lastly the **DATE_TRUNC** function to truncate the **c_date** field to the beginning of the month, so that we can group by month.

resources:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjZprLq0_79AhWAhf0HHRvlDDUQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmode.com%2Fblog%2Fdate-trunc-sql-timestamp-function-count-on%2F&usg=AOvVaw2KqDuLQZdzsC4SyXchpBcu

Comment: thanks Masterplan  - let me test and share outcome

Comment: very clean - `sum` with `partition by` did the trick